# Symfony2 call method in other Method from same Controller

Tags: symfony, methods, controller, request

Is there a possibility to call a Method inside another Method? 
I need the (twig rendered) output of the "viewAction" Method inside another method.

For the reason that I don't want to repeat myself, I thought about call the "viewAction" again, but I get an error which says:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to PrCompetitionBundle\Controller\CompetitionController::viewAction() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request, none given
```

This happens for the reason that the viewAction request an ID:

```
   public function viewAction($id,Request $request)
```

Inside The Controller, there is no Request so this error popped up.

How can I use the Method anyway?

It's because I need to output an rendered Html-content which contains twig placeholders which has to be filled.

It's not about the missing use-cases. Actually, I include folllowing (which are all neccessary):

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;
use RuntimeException;
use Wa72\HtmlPageDom\HtmlPageCrawler;
use Wa72\HtmlPageDom\HtmlPage;
```

For the Momemnt, I try to call the Action like:

```
$request->request->set('id', $partner->getUniquename());
    return $this->render('MyBundle:Output:crawl.html.twig',
        array(
            'source'=>$this->viewAction($partner->getUniquename(), $request),
            'wrapper' => $wrapper,
            )
    );
```

In the end, I simply want to render some html code which may contain some placeholders or even a form. But inside a tmeplate which will be rendered too.

Comment: How do you call `viewAction`?

Comment: I edit my question. Please have a look.

Comment: Okay, what `viewAction` is supposed to do?